# read file lines with spaces into NetLogo as lists

Tags: list, file-io, netlogo

How can I  have file contents separated by spaces read into NetLogo as a list?
For example, with a file containing data such as these:

```
  2321   23233  2  
  2321   3223   2
  2321   313    1
  213    321    1
```

I would like to create lists such as these:

```
a[2321,2321,2321,213]

b[23233,3223,313,321]

c[2,2,1,1]
```

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear that you want the first item to go in list a, the second item in list b, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here is a naive way to do it:

```
let a []
let b []
let c []
file-open "data.txt"
while [ not file-at-end? ] [
  set a lput file-read a
  set b lput file-read b
  set c lput file-read c
]
file-close
```

It assumes the number of items in your file is a multiple of 3. You will run into trouble if it isn't.

**Edit:**

...and here is a much longer, but also more general and robust way to do it:

```
to-report read-file-into-list [ filename ]
  file-open filename
  let xs []
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    set xs lput file-read xs
  ]
  file-close
  report xs
end

to-report split-into-n-lists [ n xs ]
  let lists n-values n [[]]
  while [not empty? xs] [
    let items []
    repeat n [
      if not empty? xs [
        set items lput (first xs) items
        set xs but-first xs
      ]
    ]
    foreach (n-values length items [ ? ]) [
      set lists replace-item ? lists (lput (item ? items) (item ? lists))
    ]
  ]
  report lists
end

to setup
  let lists split-into-n-lists 3 read-file-into-list "data.txt"
  let a item 0 lists
  let b item 1 lists
  let c item 2 lists
end
```

Comment: A variant on the `file-read` code is `read-from-string (word "[" file-read-line "])` — this results in a list of values. Whether the trick is applicable depends on the format of the input, but it would work for ZaC's file.

Comment: Hi, you can provide a code for read lists in netlogo, can't find it.