# How to save data of a file .txt directly in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a procedure "read-file" that is often called in ask[]. From [read file lines with spaces into NetLogo as lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244850/read-file-lines-with-spaces-into-netlogo-as-lists), this procedure reads an file .txt as lists. Is it possible to save data of a file .txt directly in Netlogo to gain time because reading a file .txt for each turtle decreases the model speed ?

```
to read-file
 let parameters split-into-n-lists 1 read-file-into-list "Parameters.txt"
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably not call `read-file` file inside `ask`. Assuming the data in the file doesn't change during the simulation, you should call it once (probably during `setup`) and access the resulting lists (saved as global variables) inside your `ask`.

And I'm not entirely sure that this is what you mean by "save data of a file .txt directly in Netlogo", but you could also initialize your lists directly in code:

```
globals [
 a b c
]

to setup
  set a [2321 2321 2321 213]
  set b [23233 3223 313 321]
  set c [2 2 1 1]
end
```